# What does it mean for a complex inner product to have $U(n)$ symmetry?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, symmetry

Does it only mean that if you have an $n$-component vector $\phi$, you can transform it with $A$, where $A\in U(n)$, so that you get $A\phi$, and then you can get the original vector $\phi$ back with $A^\dagger (A\phi)$?

Is this all the phrase "the complex inner product has $U(n)$ symmetry" means? Or are there other implications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U(n)$ symmetry for a complex inner product means the following. For any two vectors $\phi$ and $\psi$, and for any $A\in U(n)$, the inner product of $A\phi$ with $A\psi$ is the same as the inner product of $\phi$ with $\psi$:
$$\langle \psi, \phi \rangle = \langle A\psi, A\phi\rangle.$$
$A$ is therefore a symmetry in the sense that it does not change the inner product between any pairs of vectors. This is a result of the fact that $A^\dagger=A^{-1}$ for all $A\in U(n)$. Note that
$$\langle A\psi, A\phi\rangle=\langle \psi, A^\dagger A\phi\rangle=\langle \psi, A^{-1} A\phi\rangle=\langle \psi, \phi\rangle.$$